# Server not able to get message form Client

Tags: javascript, node.js

Might be a silly question but the Server can't seem to get the message sent by the Client , anyone can help?

Much Thanks
Jessi

## server.js

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
var express = require('express');

var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/sensor_db');

io.on('connection', function(socket){
  console.log('connection received from Provisioning ');

    // Message received from Client :
    socket.on('data', function(data) {
    console.log('Message from provision is : ' + ': ' + data);
  });

});

http.listen(4000, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:4000');
});
```

## Client.js

```
var io = require('socket.io-client');
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:4000', {reconnect: true});

socket.on('connect', function(socket) {
  console.log('Connected!');
});
// Client send message :
socket.emit('jessi ann george');
```

Comment: Unless 'data' is a specific trigger that I'm unaware of, you might try `socket.emit('data', 'jessi ann george');`

Comment: Why do we need to give the messages in separate quotes? Can you please explain? I;ll try that now

Comment: I have tried what you said, the Server output is :

Comment: listening on *:4000
connection received from Provisioning

Comment: The `data` is the message type & `jessi ann george` is the message.

Comment: Also recommend looking at the docs for an example...  http://socket.io/docs/

Comment: I was wrong, you can leave the namespace out according to [the docs](http://socket.io/docs/server-api/#server#emit). They show the `.emit` inside of the connect callback though.

Answer (score 1):

On the client side you are emitting by the key: `jessi ann george`.
However on the server side you are only listening for the key `data`.
Either change your client to emit `data` or change your server to listen for `jessi ann george`.

In order to pass actual data from client to server along with your key emission, you need to add a data object like:

```
socket.emit('data', { key: 'value' });
```

Server side, you would fetch this 'value' as

```
socket.on('data', function(data) {
    'Message from provision is : ' + ': ' + data.key;
});
```

It is possible to pass a simple string as your data, rather than a javascript object:

```
socket.emit('data', 'hello world');
```

And treat it server side as

```
socket.on('data', function(data) {
    'Message from provision is : ' + ': ' + data;
});
```

Sending data from server to client works by using the same syntax. Server side:

```
// read this in Adele's voice
socket.emit('server data', 'hello from the server side');
```

Client side:

```
socket.on('server data', function(data) {
    console.log('Received server data: ' + data);
});
```

Comment: How do we change the Cleint side to emit  data?

Comment: Thanks Freeman, I just wnat to send a simple message to Server, no keywords.. and the server should be able to receive it and dispay it. that's what am trying to do

Comment: Check the simple string example in my updated answer. I must say that it is very uncommon to see literal values passed through socket.io, like numbers or strings. Usually you pass JS objects. Socket.io on the background, serializes objects into *stringified* strings and unserializes them back to *parsed* objects on the receiving end.

Comment: Thanks Freeman. that worked.. Now am trying to send a message from the server to the client and the client trying to display it.. On the Server side, this doesnt work : socket.write('here is your data - 111111'); How cna the server sned a mesage and client recieve it

Comment: Thanks Frreman for the help. I need to integrate this to another code. the question to that is here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36804702/node-acting-as-a-webserver-and-a-client

Comment: Can you have a look at my other question, relating to this pls?